# Need help in mysqlquery and php

Tags: php, mysql, explode, implode

I'm doing a query like this:

```
$c = filterfunction($_POST['data']);

$sql="(descripcion LIKE '%".$c."%' or marca_repuesto LIKE '%".$c."%' or mod_nombre LIKE '%".$c."%' or anio LIKE '%".$c."%' or codigo LIKE '%".$c."%' )";

$query = mysql_query("
SELECT id,user,modelo,marca,marca_repuesto,descripcion,tipo,anio,cantidad,precio_costo,precio_lista,chasis,motor,codigo
FROM (repuestos left join marcas ON marca = m_id
left join modelos ON modelo = mod_id)
$sql 

");
```

Everything is ok, but if i add in the row repuestos.modelo two ids separated with "," don't work, and i don't know how make this works with multiple ids in this row, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: So your are trying to do - `id,id` - where each `id` is from a different table? If so, either use alias on one, or both - `id as id1, id as id2` or when accessing the array use the 0-index - `$row[0]`/`$row[1]` instead of `$row[id]`/`$row[id]`

Comment: Of course, but i will add id,id or id,id,id,id in repuestos.modelo. i think the best way is apply my query without repuestos.modelo and after, if the result = 0, explode the respuestos.modelo to search matches in the $c; What do you think? Thanks a lot Sean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear from your question what you ask.

If you want to search for a single matching id, you need

```
 WHERE id = ?
```

If you want to search for multiple matching ids, you need

```
WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)
```

Note also that your `OR LIKE` cascade

```
    descripcion LIKE '%".$c."%' 
 or marca_repuesto LIKE '%".$c."%'
 or mod_nombre LIKE '%".$c."%' 
 or anio LIKE '%".$c."%' 
 or codigo LIKE '%".$c."%'
```

is a formula for disastrously bad performance. MySQL (and any RDBMS) cannot use an index for

```
 column LIKE '%value%'
```

so it must scan the whole table. When MySQL encounters `OR` it scans the table again.

You may wish to investigate full-text search for this application.

Comment: Thanks Jones, yes i want search for a multible matching ids, from repuestos.modelo in the table modelos. i'm goin to search about the "column LIKE '%value%'" but, in the table modelos is the name of a model like "Ferrari" when i search "Ferr" i want to show result from this table and the others elements if this match. Thanks a lot for u time.

Comment: idk how explain, but this is basically what i want to do, search for a "repuesto" description, if result == 0, search matchen in te description of the models: http://i.imgur.com/X0OYWrG.png